# Unable to compile assets (Laravel Mix)

Tags: laravel, npm, node-modules

I'm unable to run npm run dev command, so i could compile my assets via Laravel Mix.
Log of the commmand:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.9.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'dev'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.12.0
3 info using node@v12.9.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle @~predev: @
6 info lifecycle @~dev: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~dev: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/mac/Desktop/projects/project/node_modules/$
9 verbose lifecycle @~dev: CWD: /Users/mac/Desktop/projects/project
10 silly lifecycle @~dev: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run development' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: @ dev: `npm run development`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:209:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:209:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd /Users/max/Desktop/projects/project
16 verbose Darwin 17.7.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.9.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v12.9.0
19 verbose npm  v6.12.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ dev: `npm run development`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Any help with understanding this log/issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the usual npm problem solutions like 1) deleting "node_modules" folder an rerunning `npm install` and  2) trying to see if there is a update available on your system for npm and node?

Comment: @xyz Deleting node modules directory and installing modules again gave me another error and log similar to the one above: 
3198 error Failed at the node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall script.
3198 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
3199 verbose exit [ 1, true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually removing the node and npm directories (https://stackabuse.com/how-to-uninstall-node-js-from-mac-osx/), then installing a fresh node and npm version solved the issue.